# Decimal exponent

Tags: exponentiation, fractions, decimal-expansion

This is how I've attacked 3^1.0987, doing it with pen and paper.  3(3)^(987/10000) = 3*3^(((3)(7)(47))/10000).  But from here I don't know what to do.  I can't imagine trying to take the 10,000th root of 3?!

Comment: Work it out with logs.

Comment: That is exactly what you do before the days of calculators and you don't have log tables.  Take the 10000th root, which is of course just take square roots 4 times and fifth roots 4 times.  (*Aside*: It looks like you are calculating $3^{\log_e 3}$?  There isn't a nice answer.)

Comment: Thanks to you both. 1.0987=log_3 (x).  (10,000th root 3)^987.  LOL, It's going to take a lot of paper.